# Finding the highest scoring player from a .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file formatted like this- 
Starplayer,1,19
Moon,3,12
Fish,4,8
Starplayer,3,9
Ellie,2,19
- With about 50 more lines,Etc.
The first column is the player name, the second is the level number (from 1-5) and the third is the score.
I want to find the player with the largest total score- so their score for each level added together. But I'm not sure as each player comes up multiple times and in a random order.
This is my code so far-

```
    def OptionC():
        PS4=open("PlayerScores.txt","r").read()
        for line in PS4:
            lines=line.split(",")
            player=lines[0]
            level=lines[1]
            score=lines[2] 
        player1=0
        score=0
        print("The overall top scorer is",player1,"with a score of",score)
```

Thanks - Please help!!!

Comment: Don't want to give you a copy/paste answer, but: loop over all the lines and compare the score to the previously remembered highest score. If it's higher then set it as the highest score. At the end of the loop you'll have the highest score.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker That could work, however I need to add together each players scores for each level. So for example, Starplayer's score = 9+19, so I guess it's the total

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a programming service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the levels do not have anything to do with the scores.

You can create lists for the players and their scores and keep updating them even if there are duplicates. At the end just find the maximum and print.

```
  def OptionC():
        PS4=open("PlayerScores.txt","r").read()
        top_player = 0
        top_score = 0
        player_list = []
        score_list = []
        for line in PS4:
            lines=line.split(",")
            player=lines[0]
            level=lines[1]
            score=lines[2] 

            #Check if the player is already in the list, if so increment the score, else create new element in the list
            if player in player_list:
                score_list[player_list.index(player)] = score_list[player_list.index(player)] + score
            else:
                player_list.append(player)
                score_list.append(score)

        top_score = max(score_list)
        top_player = player_list[score_list.index(top_score)]


        print("The overall top scorer is",top_player,"with a score of",top_score)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the score associated with each player in a `dictionary`, and add their score for each level to their total:

```
from collections import defaultdict

scores = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
with open(r"PlayerScores.txt", "r") as fh:
    for line in fh.readlines():
        player, _, score = line.split(',')
        scores[player] += int(score)

max_score = 0
for player, score in scores.items():
    if score > max_score:
        best_player = player
        max_score = score

print("Highest score is {player}: {score}".format(player=best_player, score=max_score))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't create a class? It makes really easier to manage a player profile.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, level, score):
        # initialize the arguments of the class, converting level and score in integer
        self.name = name
        self.level = int(level)
        self.score = int(score)
# create a list where all the Player objects will be saved
player_list = []
for line in open("PlayerScores.txt", "r").read().split("\n"):
    value = line.split(",")
    player = Player(value[0], value[1], value[2])
    player_list.append(player)



def OptionC():
    # sort player_list by the score
    player_list.sort(key=lambda x: x.score)
    print("The overall top scorer is", player_list[-1].name, "with a score of", player_list[-1].score)

OptionC()
```